# http header capture for mobile device to debug

Tags: android, iphone, https, packet-capture

My website is asking for authentication on iPhone but not on android.
 We have SAML enable at Apache leavel.
 To debug I need to capture http header for mobile request and want to compare the headers b/w i-phone & Androd.

On desktop all works fine.

Any guidance on how I can debug this will be very helpful.

I am aware of tcpdump  & wireshark little bit however need help since i am new bee for http headers.

Comment: tcpdump and wireshark are both excellent choices.  [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) are also commonly useful.  Just *TRY* something, and post specific questions about what you see.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use an Android APP Packet Capture to capture your packet.It can specify an app to capture its packet.You can download it by Google Play store.

Comment: Can we filter only http response and request headers. I want to compare headers info.

Comment: Packted Capture will display http headers,if can download it and try it then we discuss continue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I could able to complete capturing headers by following this link http://robandlauren.com/2013/09/14/test-on-devices/
Bit old link however by installing new version of Android Chrome plugins, all set.